# how to pass array from python to c using numpy

Tags: python, c, api, pointers

Let's say I have the following function written in C:

```
/* C-Code for calculating the average for a given dataset */

#define NOE 16

int calcAvg(float *data, float *avg)
{
    float sum; sum = 0;     

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NOE; i++) 
    {
        data[i] = i;
        sum += data[i];
    }
    avg = sum/n;

    return 0;
}
```

Now I want to pass the data from an np.array to that C function "calAvg". Also, I want the result to be stored in "result" which I defined in python.

```
# Python Code
result = float(0)

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])

myCfuncion.calc(a, result)
```

I have already created a C module and imported it into python. The problem I have is that I do not know how to pass pointers in such a way I showed.

Anybody does have an idea?

Comment: how did you import it into Python?! Read about Ctypes and https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ctypes.html

Comment: Thank you! I found out that you got to access the PyArrayObject which is a struct that conatins the data as I want it.